# How to group concat multiple record by id passed separated by comma in stored procedure?

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, stored-functions

The below is the query which i am using to get generated multiple formula based on the group concat, so the i can apply the same formula on different table. its working fine for single id by not working for comma separated id

/*id_val = '6,7'; //pased in sp paramter */

```
SET @query = (SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT('(SUM(',column_name_table,') / sum(count_of_x) ) * 100 
    as ',kpi_display_name,' ') ) FROM `formula_table` WHERE id IN (id_val) );

SELECT @query;
```

Where count_of_x is static value; column_name_table is the field in formula_table

but the above query return single value;

table structure as

```
CREATE TABLE `formula_table` (
      `id` int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
      `column_name_table` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL
      PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
    ) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=84 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci;





insert  into `formula_table`(`id`,`column_name_table`) values 
(5,'higest_record'),
(6,'higest_salary'),
(7,'higest_employee'),
(9,'higest_x');
```

Answer (score 0):

I Have try this problem is resolved

```
SET @g_formula  = "";
SET @query = CONCAT('   select group_concat(column_table_name) into @g_formula from (
            select concat("(sum(",column_table_name,")/","sum(count_of_x)) * 100 as ",column_table_name) as column_table_name

            from (

            select column_table_name from formula_table

            where id in (',id_val,')  

             ) as aa ) as bb

    ');
SELECT @query;
PREPARE stmt FROM @query;
EXECUTE stmt;

SELECT @g_formula;
```